# Highlighting a the used cells in a particular row

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I am writing VBA for a file at work and need to do something a little odd.  I need to highlight the row (not the entire row, just the used part of the row) if the cell in Column J contains a certain value.  I have figured everything out except my code is highlighting the entire row, and I only want it to highlight the used cells in that row.  Can anyone advise?  Code below

```
'Yellow Highlight..........THIS IS HIGHLIGHTING THE WHOLE ROW....WHY!!!!! WHY!!!!!!!!!!!
Sheets("EMM").Activate
    With Sheets("EMM")
        For Lrow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                With .Cells(Lrow, "J")
                    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                        If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
                            .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        End If
                    End If
                End With
        Next Lrow
    End With
```

Comment: Because .EntireRow applies the color to the entire row...  You will ahve to check each column and color the cells of the row not the entire row..

Comment: `.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`'s EntireRow is causing the entire row to be highlighted. To highlight a particular cell use something like `Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
With Sheets("EMM")
    For Lrow = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        With .Cells(Lrow, "J")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "Desk to adjust" Then
                    Sheets("EMM").UsedRange.Rows(Lrow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

or using AutoFilter

```
With Sheets("EMM").UsedRange
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="Desk to adjust"
    .Rows(1).Hidden = True      'Header row
    .Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    .Rows(1).Hidden = False     'Header row
    .AutoFilter
    .Cells(1, 1).Activate
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest to avoid looping on the row and fetching non-blank cells, or setting up a filter, is to do this inside the IF:

```
.UsedRange.Rows(lRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
.UsedRange.Rows(lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
```

(highlight the row then unhighlight empty cells)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some commented code showing how to use the Range.AutoFilter method to achieve the results you're looking for.  No looping required, so it is generally much more efficient:

```
Sub tgrFilter()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim strMatch As String

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EMM")       'We will be working with sheet "EMM" in activeworkbook
    Set rngData = ws.Range("J1").CurrentRegion  'Get the region that column J is a part of in order to limit the highlighting (so it doesn't highlight entire row)
    strMatch = "Desk to adjust"                 'This is the string/value we are looking for in column J
    rngData.Interior.Color = xlNone             'Clear any previous highlighting

    On Error Resume Next    'If there are no results, it would cause an error

    'Work with just column J within rngData
    With Intersect(rngData, ws.Columns("J"))
        .AutoFilter 1, strMatch     'Note that the filter is not case sensitive

        'Color the matching rows contained in the data (not the entire row)
        Intersect(rngData, .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

        .AutoFilter     'Remove the filter
    End With

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Error occurred which means there were no results
        MsgBox "No matches found in column J for [" & strMatch & "]", , "No results"
        Err.Clear
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0         'Remove the On Error Resume Next condition

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Formatting instead of macro.

Select the cell your need to highlight and at menu bar go to Format -> Conditional Formatting
[image]

In dialog select condition you need to check, this example check if cell value is equal to 'AA'. You can add condition up to 3 conditions at a time
[image]

Next, Click format button to format cell when the condition is true.
[image]

After finish all click OK to close dialog you will get the highlight you need.
[image]